# How can I get a total count across all buckets in a terms aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using a elasticsearch `terms` aggregation to bucket based on an array property on each document. I'd like to get the total number of *documents* in each bucket.

Let's say each document is a `Post`, and has an array property `media` which specifies which social media website the post is on (and may be empty):

```
{
   id: 1
   media: ["facebook", "twitter", "instagram"]
}
{
   id: 2
   media: ["twitter", "instagram", "tiktok"]
}
{
   id: 3
   media: ["instagram"]
}
{
   id: 4
   media: []
}
```

And here's my `terms` aggregation on `media`.

```
"aggs": {
    "Posts_by_media": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "media",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will return the following:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "Posts_by_media": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,   
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,           
      "buckets": [                        
        {
          "key": "instagram",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "twitter",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "facebook",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "tiktok",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Along with this result, I want to know the total number of *documents* in these buckets.

As you can see, the documents will be counted for *each* value in `media`. So, the post with `id: 1` will count for the three buckets of `facebook`, `twitter` and `instagram`.

So, it will not suffice to add each of the bucket counts together. I'll end up with **7**, where the correct answer should be **3** (because the document with `media: []` will not be included in any bucket).

**Is there a way to return the total number of documents in these buckets?**

Looking at the docs a bit, it seems like it's possible that I could use another aggregation, an [exists aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-exists-query.html), like so:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "filter": {
      "exists": {
        "field": "media"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, I don't feel great about the fact that this is a separate aggregation -- it feels like If I'm not careful, I could get the two out of sync.

What's the recommendation here?

Answer (score 0):

From your description you want to query the number of data where `media` is not empty?If so, you can use the following query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "media"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

the `total` from response is the number of hits in this query.

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I do want the number of documents where `media` is not empty. But, is there a way I can get this in the same aggregation? Ideally, it feels like the `terms` aggregation would return this information as a toplevel `doc_count`, but that's not the case.

Comment: You can try the following aggregation :)

`{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"media"}}]}},"aggs":{"count":{"cardinality":{"field":"media"}}},"size":0}`